# Center button in Bootstrap navbar (outside collapse)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to have a button in the navbar that is:

- inline with the rest of the navbar items (i.e. it doesn't get pushed to the next line);
- located outside of the collapsed navbar section; and
- always positioned in the center of the page for all screen resolutions (including when the right-side of the navbar is collapsed).

I am having particular problems with:

- centering the button; and
- some of the navbar items not working for smaller screen resolutions (when navbar is collapsed).

Below is my code.

Alternative CSS that I tried:

```
.navbar-button {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

but this caused some of the other navbar links to not work. I subsequently tried to make use of `z-index`, but it didn't seem to work.

```css
body {
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.section {
  margin-bottom: 30cm;
}
.navbar-button {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">

  <title>Test</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#brand">Brand</a>
        <div class="navbar-button">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary navbar-btn">Button</button>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="text-center">
            <a href="#link1">Link-1</a>
          </li>
          <li class="text-center">
            <a href="#link2">Link-2</a>
          </li>
          <li class="text-center">
            <a href="#link3">Link-3</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="section" id="brand">
        <h3>Top</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="section" id="link1">
        <h3>Section-1</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="section" id="link2">
        <h3>Section-2</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="section" id="link3">
        <h3>Section-3</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use position : absolute but don't apply 100% width as it's mostly likely covering your links/toggle button. You can also apply the .navbar-btn directly to the button inside of an outer div.

**Example CSS:**

```
.button-center {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

**Working Example:**

```css
body {
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.section {
  margin-bottom: 30cm;
}
.button-center {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="https://www.github.com" target="_blank">Brand</a>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary navbar-btn button-center">Button</button>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="text-center">
          <a href="https://www.github.com" target="_blank">Test Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="text-center">
          <a href="#link2">Link-2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="text-center">
          <a href="#link3">Link-3</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="section" id="brand">
      <h3>Top</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="section" id="link1">
      <h3>Section-1</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="section" id="link2">
      <h3>Section-2</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="section" id="link3">
      <h3>Section-3</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```